# Pug/Jade interpolation not working for attributes

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a page which I am rendering like this:

```
res.render('account.pug', {user: req.user._id})
```

—and which is supposed to show a profile picture which corresponds to the user like this:

```
img(id='profilepicture' src='profilepictures/#{user}')
```

However, the Pug renders as:

```
<img id='profilepicture' src='profilepictures/#{users}' />
```

—instead of:

```
<img id='profilepicture' src='profilepictures/USERID' />
```

—so the correct profile picture does not display.

It is weird because when I write `div #{user}` it renders  correctly as `<div>USERID</div>`, so it clearly has something to do with it being that I am interpolating on an attribute mid-string. I have tried using back ticks instead of quote marks but this did not work either.

Answer (score 5):

As [noted in the Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation), the `#{foo}` interpolation syntax is no longer supported in attributes.

Instead of using—

```
img#profilepicture(src='profilepictures/#{user}') // no longer supported
```

—you can use (as @Shinigami points out):

```
img#profilepicture(src='profilepictures/' + user) // supported
```

Or, if you have ES6 support, you can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
img#profilepicture(src=`profilepictures/${user}`) // supported
```

(Note that the last one uses `${}` instead of `#{}`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
img#profilepicture(src='profilepictures/' + users)
```

Docs: https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

Helpful Site: https://pughtml.com