# Why does this object in my pug template working incorrectly as an attribute but correctly as raw text?

Tags: pug

The `obj.lang` is translated well under the `<b>` tag. But it's not working for the `<html>` attribute. What do I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please refer to this answer and upvote if you find it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439639/pug-jade-interpolation-not-working-for-attributes/59456532#59456532. Also, please copy and paste your code into the question instead of adding screenshots in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have upvoted :)