# Integrating variables into .pug classes

Tags: html, variables, pug

I currently have .pug code that looks like this:

```
a.item
    .ui.green.horizontal.label something
    .ui.basic.grey.label 
        | {{ variable1 }} descrip1
    .ui.basic.green.label
      | {{ variable2 }} descrip2
    .ui.basic.grey.label
      | {{ variable3 }} descrip3
```

I would like to make the colors of the individual ui elements dynamic based on the values in the variables. So for example, if variable1 > 30, the ui element would be

```
ui.basic.green.label
```

whereas if variable1 < 10, the ui element would be

```
ui.basic.red.label
```

Is there a way to do this in .pug? I just get multiple divs when I try and make each component dynamic. As a note, I tried

```
ui.basic.{{color_variable}}.label
```

or something to that effect, but obviously this is incorrect syntax and it didn't compile properly.

I'm very new to HTML and .pug and any help is appreciated!

EDIT: The solution that worked for me (with Sean's help) was escaping the character using the # key.

```
.ui(class= "basic #{color_variable} label")
```

or

```
.ui.basic.label(class= "#{color_variable}")
```

EDIT2: Apparently the above is deprecated, please look at Sean's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible when using the standard [attribute syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html) for classes instead of the [class literal syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#class-literal) (or when combining the two).

Here's an example of how to do that with your markup.

This Pug—

```
.ui.basic.label(class= color)
```

—will compile to this HTML—

```
<div class="ui basic label green"></div>
```

—if the value of the `color` Pug variable is `"green"`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! When I try this, it outputs the error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'let'`. Should I be declaring that variable in a particular place?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you weren't using Pug variables. You're passing Jinja variables to Pug?

Comment: Yeah, that's just the structure of the project I'm working within. With your edit, I get `Unexpected Tokens`. Sorry for the trouble, this seems like it should be a fairly simple thing to implement but I haven't found documentation to help with this problem.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out! It needs to be escaped like `.ui(class= "basic #{default_color} label")`. Thanks for your help, I'll accept your answer and edit my question above!

Comment: If `default_color` is a variable in Pug, that syntax has been deprecated and won't work in the latest versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439639/pug-jade-interpolation-not-working-for-attributes/59456532#59456532